# Any difference between 损害,损伤,伤害?

Tags: meaning, difference

I am having a hard time to decide which to use between the three options (损害，损伤 and 伤害)...

Anyone can teach me the difference?

Comment: What's the context you want to use them for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

损害,损伤,伤害

损伤 is generally a noun. The other 2 can be both noun and verb, with 损害 much more frequently a verb than noun.

损伤 generally implies physical damage.

伤害 can be both physical and psychological or spiritual.

损害 when used as a verb has a derogatory connotation, while the other 2 do not.

Answer (score 4):

The literal meanings of the three words share much in common: to cause damage or harm. Usages can sometimes be distinguished by the intention and effect of the action.

损害: to damage, to undermine

损伤: to injure or harm

伤害: to hurt

The drum player says he feels **hurt** by his neighbours‘ complaint that his loud music **harms** people's hearing and **damages** the image of the peaceful neighbourhood.

鼓手说他感到**伤害**，因为邻居们投诉他大声的音乐**损伤**听觉，并且**损害**社区安宁的形象。

Answer (score 2):

损害 is more common than 伤害 is much more common than 损伤, otherwise they are identical. Use them all to avoid repetition.